# Elements of list change despite cloning in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates, variable-assignment, cloning

In the following Python code, I created a list a which contains a number of lists, and then created a copy of it, b, but unlike with lists that do not contain other lists, when b is changed, a also changes accordingly. Can someone explain how to prevent this from happening other than by copying each list separately?

```
a = [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
b=a[:]
b[0][0] = 5
a
[[5, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is a shallow copy of `a` (check out the values `id(a[0])` and `id(b[0])`, they will be same even if `id(a)` != `id(b)`). You need to take care of the elements inside the list as well (if they are mutable and modified, a shallow copy will reflect the changes in both the places). You can do something like this to create a `deep` copy:

```
import copy
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Read up on [shallow and deep copy operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#:%7E:text=A%20shallow%20copy%20constructs%20a,objects%20found%20in%20the%20original.) in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The slice creates a new list, but the contents of the list are not copied. So, `a[:]` gets you a new list, but the contents of that new list `b` are still references to the same lists that are referenced from `a`.

If you would try `b[0]=[]`, you'd be able to tell you can modify `b` without changing `a`, but `b[0][0]` just modifies the first element of the first list in `b`, which is the first element of the first list in `a` as well.